# Looking for an Italian cheese similar/identical to the French Brie

Tags: substitutions, cheese, italian-cuisine, brie

I am looking for a an Italian cheese that I can use as substitute to Brie.
It should have the same consistency and creaminess, as well as delicate flavour.

Any suggestion?

EDIT: This question could benefit by defining how Brie is made, so I could go in an Italian diary shop and ask for something made with a similar process

Comment: Erm... why not just use... brie?  Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Yes of course there is a reason :). Its for a competition and wanted to use only Italian ingriedients but have created a recipe that is perfect with brie. I tried substituting it with different types of Italian cheese (e.g. light Pecorino, Tosella, Puzzone, Gorgonzola) but it doesn't result in the same delicate flavour that Brie can give. I am aware that Italy has 300+ types of cheeses so there must be something out there that will fit :). I'll go and speak with a local diary farm tomorrow and try grasp some more info :)

Comment: +1 for a great question.  fyi, the category of cheese you're looking for is called 'washed rind'.  It'll help your cheesemonger narrow down the choices.  The mold is [Penicillium camemberti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penicillium_camemberti).  Would you reporting back when you try the Alpino? some of us are curious ;)

Comment: @MandoMando I managed to find some Alpino from the Italian brand Osella. It tastes similar, if not idenitcal to many "mainstream" bries but it has not the same creaminess of the Brie I wanted to use. As far as I understand from the answers I got it probably on how long they have been seasoned for. Is it correct to say that longer "seasoned" bries will be more creamy and hence the Alpino I tried must have been seasoned only for a minimum amount of time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most similar, of course, the one you could easily find in any supermarket, is the "**Camoscio d'Oro**". This is not similar but the same, since is made by [Bongrain SA](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bongrain), a French food group.

As semi-industrial cheese made in Italy, we have the "[**Alpino**](http://www.fattorieosella.it/it/formaggi-osella/prodotti/piumati/alpino-osella)", better or similar to "**paglietta**", both of Osella, which is sited in Piemonte (Turin), region on the border with France.

But all over the region there are many small firms dairy, which produce the "[**tomini**](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomino_(formaggio))". Tomini are a tipical regional cheese, smaller but very similar to brie, both as flavor, as texture and as aging. [**some news**](http://egofelix.com/4774-tomini-or-tomino-cheese)
[image: tomini]
[image: tomini 2]

You can find tomini freshly made​​, very sweet and tender, and, day by day, more and more seasoned tomini. The last ones can be done on the grill.

If you switch to production typical, you can find a variety of high-quality productions of tomini and similar products in many farms in the region. Like "[**Montebore**](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montebore_(formaggio))" or "**Bra**", or very similar products that, if you are lucky, you can find among the reserved ones from some kind local farmer.

We share a border, mountains, traditions, people. We even have a whole region half Italian and half French, the Val d'Aosta. Incidentally also some cheese!

Comment: Thanks Viola, this is a more complete answer. I went to my local store and found some Tomino, however they are not identical. I have ordered some "Alpino" and hope that they will be fine. The owner confirmed that they should be similar to Brie.

Answer (score 1):

[FoodSubs](http://www.foodsubs.com/Chesoft.html) claims [Paglietta](http://t.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paglietta) is similar.

I don't read Italian, so I don't know what the Italian language wiki says about it.

Comment: Thanks, it does look similar to brie and I remember trying it once. I will go in a shop tomorrow and try buying it to see if it works :). Thanks for the link :). http://www.fattorieosella.it/it/formaggi-osella/prodotti/specialita-da-banco/paglietta

Answer (score 1):

Brie is a soft cheese that is characterized by its creamy texture and velvety rind.

It is only aged for two weeks to five at around sixty degrees Fahrenheit.

Its unique texture and flavor is a result of the mold that is allowed to grow on its surface. The mold partially digests the young cheese and creates the creamy texture. When the cheese is wrapped the mold is smashed and becomes the rind.

http://www.cheesemaking.com/store/pg/22-Brie.html

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, it helps me to have an idea on what to ask and improve my "food culture"

Comment: Wikipedia [disagrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brie) on the aging time ("at least four to five weeks"). French Wikipedia says that [brie de Melun](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brie_de_Melun) is aged at 12C for a week then 7C for 3+ weeks, and the [AoC regulations](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000000308356) require a minimum aging of 4 weeks.

Comment: @PeterTaylor- fair enough. Four weeks is still a fairly young cheese.

Comment: Aging time depends on which are the conditions of temperature / heat / moisture / airiness of the rooms where the forms are stored. Every location is different and the farmers/manufacturers know very well their own rooms. It is not a fixed element, so you have just to look at the calendar. The cheeses ​​good made are checked every day, to check the degree of ripeness.